# Xamarin Forms, no unitybootstrapper

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I figure this should be very simple to fix but this is driving me totally crazy because I can't find any information about this problem.

I have created a "Blank APP (Portable)" in VS2015.
Next I used NuGet package manager to update and or install:

Xamarin.Forms v2.3.1.114

Prism.Core & Prism.Forms & Prism.Unity.Forms v6.2.0

Unity v4.0.1

--

So I want to create a bootstrapper that derives from the "UnityBootstrapper" however it can't seem to find it and suggesting to me to generate a new class.

Here are the references:

[image]

In which Assembly can I find this UnityBootstrapper?

In all the tutorials there seems to be no problem inheriting from the unitybootstrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no more bootstrapper.  As noted in the release notes, this has been removed.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/wiki/Release-Notes-6.2.0

You should be using PrismApplication now.  Also look at the getting started in the docs

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/1-GettingStarted.md

Comment: Thanks! I have been using 'old' tutorials like the one you made at your website "/first-look-at-the-prism-for-xamarin-forms-preview/" so I was really confused.

Comment: Yeah, I'll be publishing an updated blog post soon with the changes for the new 6.2.0 version.

Comment: FYI - The Getting Started document is now at https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/docs/Xamarin-Forms/1-Getting-Started.md